# Need point of view to this exercise : Primitive

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello everybody my friend and I are doing an exercise but we don't agree on the beginning. Actually we are trying to find the primitive of the function below. So I was wondering if you could take a look at it and give us your point of veiw . Or if you think there is an other way to resolve it please tell me.

$$ A = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{2x+3} \mathrm{d}x $$

The substitution $ t =  2x + 3  \;\implies\; x = (t-3)/2 $,
and I found as result $$\ 3/2 \ln (3/5) $$

Comment: @hardmath alright my badlet me please edit it

Comment: Note that there are two parts involved in rewriting the definite integral.  One is the integrand, and the other is the combined limits of integration.   It is possible to take more than one approach, though of course the ultimate value of the definite integral should be the same.

Comment: but with my method i have this result = $$\ 3/2 (ln3 - ln5) $$

Comment: As shown both ways are wrong because the limits of integration in terms of $x$ are simply copied for $t=2x+3$, which is not correct.  I'm sure you have arrived at your result by changing the limits of integration, but it isn't shown.

Comment: I improved on your edit to give an idea how some of what you drew in the image could be expressed.

Comment: alright and thank yyou

Answer (score 0):

It can be way done easier. No need for a substitution, this is a bit overkill.

HINT:
$$\frac{x}{2x+3}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x+3}{2x+3}-\frac{1\frac{1}{2}}{2x+3}$$

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: but isn't $$\ \frac{-1( \frac{3}{2})}{2x+3}$$

Comment: @KA.Bornin what do you mean?